# Removing kitchen tap limescale

Tags: plumbing-fixture

Cannot remove kitchen taps because of limescale buildup. Taps hidden by underside of bowl, therefore v. Difficult to get to. The limescale is blocking the threads for the hot tap (obviously the cold can be unscrewed by hand

Comment: Can you get pliers in there to break the limescale by crushing it? (Of course, don't damage the threads or you will have a new problem.) Can you add a photo of the situation to your question?

Comment: Where, exactly are the threads you're referring to? What are referred to as "taps" in my area would not be on the underside, and kitchens don't usually have separate ones for hot and cold.

Comment: @fixer1234 Separate hot and cold taps are still quite common in the UK ((though mixers are probably more common for kitchens by now).  The tap in question is above the bowl, but it has a threaded pipe which goes through a hole in the bowl, and the tap is fastened in place by a nut screwed down onto the bowl.  The OP wishes to remove this nut, but it is held by limescale.

Answer (score 2):

## 3 Ways to deal with plumbing that has seized due to lime scale

### 1 More torque

Get the biggest wrench your space will allow and use it to loosen the plumbing.
Alternatively, you can try using a pipe to extend the leverage you have on an existing wrench.

### 2 Descaling

1. Go to the dollar store and buy some 'cleaning vinegar' (and a spray bottle if you don't have one).
2. Pour the cleaning vinegar into an empty spray bottle and close it.
3. Thoroughly spray the area with the lime scale
4. Wait 10 min
5. Repeat steps 3 and 4 until lime scale is satisfactorily removed

## 3 Cut and replace the fitting

When the other two methods don't work, or you have plenty of pipe to work with, you can use a pipe cutter, pipe saw, or oscillating saw to cut to the affected are and replace the fitting. 
This method is the one I generally use, as trying to salvage something with a lot of buildup is time consuming and not likely to re-seal well.

**Going forward you'll want to address the reason for the scale build-up (water pressure too high / improperly sealed connection) and possibly think about installing a descaling filter on your water main to protect appliances and any fancy shower heads.**

Comment: [CLR](https://clrbrands.com/Products/CLR-Household/CLR-Calcium-Lime-Rust-Remover) might be even better than vinegar.

Comment: @fixer1234 I haven't found CLR to work much better than house hold vinegar to justify the price difference.  If you really want something strong, pick up some 'grout removal acid', or Phosphoric Acid from the home store.